# sql set variable where couple of conditions are met

Tags: mysql, sql

I just wonder how to update row in table1, if couple of values from table1 and table2 are equal.

for example, table1 have rows:

```
id - password - attemp
user  secret       0
user2  pass        0
```

and table2 have rows"

```
id -  password
user   secret
user2   kek
```

update table1 attemp value, where table1 user and password are equal and table1 attemp = 0, to table1 attemp = 1

I did something like this(and it does not work):

```
UPDATE a1
set a1.attemp = '1'
from table1 a1
JOIN table2 a2
on a1.user = a2.user AND a1.password = a2.password
WHERE 
a1.attemp != 1
```

Comment: what is the point in having two tables? table 2 contains the exact same information from table 1!

Comment: I have two tables, from diffrent databases but with the same values, and have to validate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 a1
INNER JOIN table2 a2 ON a1.id = a2.id AND a1.password = a2.password
SET a1.attemp = '1'
WHERE a1.attemp != '1'
```

This will result in :

```
ID  PASSWORD    ATTEMP
user    secret  1
user2   pass    0
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41a3c/1)</kbd>